# I thought my period started at sahoor,so i didn’t make neeyat for the fast. Now i don't see any blood and discharge is white.Can make neeyat now and

Tags: women

I was in doubt if my period came at sahoor. So I didnt make neeyah for the fast. Its afternoon and I don't see any blood, just the white discharge.  Can I make the neeyat now and keep the fast? Also can I pray namaz?
If yes do I need to take a shower before praying?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. The topic of niyyah is covered on the site. What hinders you from praying and fasting if you don't see any discharge. In fact you should never base your acts on doubt. Stop fasting and praying if you see discharge not before.

Comment: Actually I saw that my discharge was a bit pinkish brown in the toilet bowl, so I didn't keep the fast thinking period has arrived but now when I checked it with a tissue, it came out clean.

Answer (score 0):

For obligatory fasts you have to make the intention (niyyah) before fajr. An intention made at the beginning of Ramadan to fast for the whole month of Ramadan is also sufficient unless it’s broken (by being sick, traveling, etc.), then you would need to make a new one. And what you experienced is most likely spotting before the period. So for that you can pray and fast as usual but you need to perform wudu before each salat.
Allah knows best.

> Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever does not have the intention of fasting before Fajr, there is no fast for him.”